# Add alt text to image from previous accordion header

Tags: jquery

I would like to add the content of an H3 tag in a jQuery accordion to the "alt" text of an image in the sibling DIV. I have tried a variety of methods without success, and this code seems logical to me, but still doesn't work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is the (simplified)  HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Some stuff here</h3>
    <div>
        <img src="some_place.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </div>
    ...(repeat several times)
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    $( "img" ).each(function() {
        var $title = $(this).prev( "h3" ).text();
        $(this).attr( "alt", $title )
        });
});
```

This code seems to me like it would work, but bupkiss... here is the image code in the browser:

```
<img src="some_place.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt>
```

Comment: Have any errors in the console?

Comment: David Stetler is correct about j08691 being correct.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).prev( "h3" ).text();` won't work because it selects the previous element, and there is no element that's previous relative to the image. Instead use:

```
$(this).parent().prev("h3").text();
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5x1pwrwj/1)**

Comment: D'oh! It's so obvious now! The H3 tag was a sibling of the DIV holding the IMG. /facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Isherwood & David is correct: j08691 is correct. I failed to notice that the DIV is the sibling of the H3 tag.